# Sending data through/to a socket created on a separate thread

Tags: python

I'm writing some software for a weather station that I'm making. This software runs on a raspberry pi to send collected data to other computers over the network using Python's sockets functionality. However, I'm having trouble multi-threading it.

The main code runs in an infinite loop to save the data at the beginning of every minute, but it also has to manage connections from clients to the device as well, independently of collecting the data. Once the data has been collected it needs to be sent to the connected clients.

I've put the code that manages client connections (using `socket.accept()`) into a separate thread, however in order to send messages to those connected clients I need to access that thread and retrieve the `connection` variable that contains the clients. This obviously isn't possible.

Normally with a problem like this I'd create a global variable and copy the contents of the `connection` into it so I could then access it from anywhere, but I don't know the type so cannot declare this variable.

Below is my code.

```
import serial
import socket
import threading
import time
import datetime
import os

dataFilePath = "/home/pi/Weather_Station/stationData.xml"

# Open serial communications port to arduino
weatherStation = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600);

print("STATUS: station software initialised on " + datetime
     .datetime.now().strftime("%A %d of %B %Y at %H:%M:%S"))

# Create data logging file if doesn't exist
if os.path.isfile(dataFilePath) == False:

   dataFileA = open(dataFilePath, "w")
   dataFileA.write(
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><stationData></stationData>")
   dataFileA.close()

   # Output data file creation timestamp
   print("STATUS: data logging file created on " + datetime
         .datetime.now().strftime("%A %d of %B %Y at %H:%M:%S"))


# Allow devices to connect to station for data retrieval
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind to IP address and listen for connections
server.bind(("192.168.0.31", 8888))
server.listen(10)


# Accept clients on separate thread
def my_tcp_server():
   connection, address = server.accept()

   print("STATUS: ip " + connection
         .recv(1024) + " connected to station")
   connection.sendall("connection successful")

# Run a seperate thread to allow accepting clients individually from recording data
threading.Thread(target=my_tcp_server).start()

print("STATUS: available for network access on " + datetime
     .datetime.now().strftime("%A %d of %B %Y at %H:%M:%S"))


while True:

   # Constanly read port to prevent buffer build up
   weatherStation.readline()

   # Log data at begining of every minute
   if datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S") == "00":

       report = weatherStation.readline().replace("\r\n", "")
       timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(
           ).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

       finalReport = "<report time=\"" + timestamp + "\" " + report

       # Send data to all connected clients
       connection.sendall(finalReport.encode())

       with open(dataFilePath, "rb+") as dataFileB:
           dataFileB.seek(-14, os.SEEK_END)
           dataFileB.truncate()

           # Record data to file
           dataFileB.write(finalReport)
           dataFileB.write("</stationData>")

       print(finalReport)
```

How can I accept clients to my server on a separate thread so it doesn't block the data collection, but still send messages to the clients from outside this thread?